# Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Suppose we have the following documents in a MongoDB collection:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"blue"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"red"
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4193"),
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"black"
      },
      {  
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"green"
      }
   ]
}
```

And the MongoDB query is

```
db.test.find({"shapes.color": "red"}, {_id: 0, 'shapes.$': 1});
```

Can someone tell me how to write it in Java?

I am using:

```
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
obj1.add(new BasicDBObject("shapes.color", "red"));
List<BasicDBObject> obj1 = new ArrayList<>();
obj2.add(new BasicDBObject("shapes.$", "1"));

BasicDBObject parameters1 = new BasicDBObject();
parameters1.put("$and", obj1);

DBCursor cursor = table.find(parameters1,obj2).limit(500);
```

and I am not getting anything.

Comment: Don't use list. Just create BasicDBObject one for each query and projection and pass it to find. Something like `BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("shapes.color", "red");    BasicDBObject obj1 = new BasicDBObject("shapes.$", "1");           DBCursor cursor = table.find(obj,obj1).limit(500);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the [Mongo Shell `find` function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is:

> `db.collection.find(query, projection)`
>
> **query**     *document*  Optional. Specifies selection filter using query operators. To return all documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty document ({}).
>
> **projection** *document*     Optional. Specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter.

When translating this for execution by the Mongo Java driver you need to construct separate `BasicDBObject` instances for;

- the query
- the projection

Here's an example:

```
MongoCollection<Document> table = ...;

// {"shapes.color": "red"}
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("shapes.color", "red");

// {_id: 0, 'shapes.$': 1}
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("shapes.$", "1").append("_id", 0);

FindIterable<Document> documents = table
    // assign the query
    .find(query)
    // assign the projection
    .projection(projection);

System.out.println(documents.first().toJson());
```

Given the sample documents included in your question the above code will print out:

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "shape": "circle",
      "color": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is identical to the output from `db.test.find({"shapes.color": "red"}, {_id: 0, 'shapes.$': 1});`.